# New User Documentation - Active Directory Infrastructure

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, exchange-2010

I have done some quick googling to try and find a 'template' to use to create a document for setting up new user accounts on an Active Directory domain. We aspire to keep a standard across our client sites.

Does anybody have anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you are looking for a checklist of steps necessary to add a user, localized factors that you will need to take into consideration include:

- What platform/service is being used for e-mail, and whether it is synchronized with the domain
- Whatever the client's localized rules are for setting domain usernames and e-mail addresses
- Whether the client has non-AD-integrated applications or services that require the creation of redundant user accounts
- The need to follow the client's localized procedures for communicating the initial temporary password to the new user
- Any client-specific *and role-specific* expectations for security group membership

Checklists are fantastic, but they are not one-size-fits-all. Standardization may be a good way to make your job a little easier and more predictable, but you need to take your clients' specific needs and expectations into consideration. After all, paying attention to their business needs is what they hired you to do.

I would suggest creating your own checklist for each of your clients. Store them in a centralized and orderly fashion, and be sure to refer to them whenever they are needed.